# Mvvmcross WithFormat() not firing

Tags: ios, converters, mvvmcross

I'm trying to formatting a byte[] to a string for displaying in IOs application, here what 
The problem is that the Converter never fires up
I actually have:

Converter class

```
class ByteArrayToTextValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<byte[], string>
{

    protected override string Convert(byte[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is byte[])
        {
            return "test";
            /*
            var byteArray = (byte[])value;
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
             */
        }
        return "";
    }

    protected override byte[] ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            var text = (string)value;
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        }
        return new byte[] { };
    }
}
```

View scrap:

```
var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(
    TableView,
    SubtitleDetailViewCell.Key,
    SubtitleDetailViewCell.Key
);
TableView.Source = source;
TableView.RowHeight = 50;

TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(SubtitleDetailViewCell), SubtitleDetailViewCell.Key);

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ObservationsView, ObservationsViewModel>();
set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.Observations);
//set.Bind(source).For(s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To(vm => vm.SelectedObsCommand);
set.Apply();

TableView.ReloadData();
```

Custom cell class:

```
public SubtitleDetailViewCell(IntPtr handle)
    : base(handle)
{
    Initialize();

    this.DelayBind(() =>
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SubtitleDetailViewCell, ObservationMedicale>();
        set.Bind(MainLbl).To(observation => observation.Texte).WithConversion("ByteArrayToText");
        set.Bind(SubLeftLbl).To(observation => observation.SaisieLe);
        set.Bind(SubRightLbl).To(observation => observation.PraticienNom);
        set.Apply();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be as simple as the fact that your `ByteArrayToTextValueConverter` is `internal` rather than `public` - so MvvmCross doesn't have permission to access it.

If you do want to keep it `internal`, then you can also use the alternative format of `WithConversion`:

```
  .WithConversion(new ByteArrayToTextValueConverter(), null);
```

---

Beyond that, I'm also unsure why you would apply the `ByteArrayToText` conversion on the list of `Observations` - it looks more like the source should be a collection of `ObservationMedicale` objects

Comment: indeed my example is wrong, the Conversion is done in the custom cell with one ObservationMedicale object (the ".WithConversion("StringLength");" conversion was just a simple test)